# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: laravel-5, database-migration

Good afternoon,

I have a problem I've been trawling over for a few days and cant seem to get my head around. Just wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction. I'm using :
 - Laravel Version: 5.8.
 - PHP Version: 7.2.5
 - Database Driver & Version: mysql
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?
I appreciate your replies!

Stacktrace:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\crm\database\migrations\2018_07_18_054859_create_counters_table.php on line 28 at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\crm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:2611
    2607|      *
    2608|      * @param  array  $values
    2609|      * @return bool
    2610|      */
  > 2611|     public function insert(array $values)
    2612|     {
    2613|         // Since every insert gets treated like a batch insert, we will make sure the
    2614|         // bindings are structured in a way that is convenient when building these
    2615|         // inserts statements by verifying these elements are actually an array.

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\crm\database\migrations\2018_07_18_054859_create_counters_table.php:28

  2   CreateCountersTable::load()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\crm\database\migrations\2018_07_18_054859_create_counters_table.php:23

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

This is my 018_07_18_054859_create_counters_table.php code

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCountersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('counters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('key')->unique();
            $table->string('prefix')->unique();
            $table->integer('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        $this->load();
    }

    protected function load()
    {
        DB::table('counters')->insert(config('crm.counters'));
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('counters');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `2018_07_18_054859_create_counters_table.php` file.

Comment: done! would appreciate a help from your side!

Comment: What does your config folder's `crm.counters` look like? Seems like whatever's returned from there isn't a valid array.